# Is it possible to encrypt Word Docs with something other than default?

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption

AES 128-bit advanced encryption is fairly simple to break and was wondering if there was any way to use a more secure one? And if so - any suggestions?

Comment: AES is easy to break?  Really?  Any basis for this assertion?

Comment: @Xander I stand corrected, I've always heard that AES 128-bit was far less secure than AES 256-bit.  I just looked it up and they are essentially the same.  Bigger numbers look more secure I guess.  Saw the comparison "Why do people buy the Red sports car over the Blue one?" It doesn't make it any faster, it's just a preference.  Sorry

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for!  But yes, given currently foreseeable technology, AES-128 is plenty secure.  AES-256 is theoretically stronger against some attacks, but not practically stronger. (And it's slower to boot.)

Comment: The biggest vulnerability with any reasonable encryption algorithm is the password that secures the crypto key.  If you use "password" or anything in the list of top 10,000 passwords, your crypto can be "cracked" in 5,000 tries on the average.  (The quotes are there because it isn't really the cryptographic algorithm or key that gets cracked.)  Look into Diceware (http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html">Diceware), and have a look at this list: https://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/

Comment: Diceware link above is broken, and it's too late to edit.  Sorry.  http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html